# Is it possible to put a border around two partials in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to Rails, so bear with me here.
Here's my haml file where I'm rendering my two partials.

```
 = render partial: 'stepwizard', locals: {active: 'payment'}

 = render partial: 'form-payment', locals: {quotation_request: @quotation_request}
```

I want to put a border around those two partials.

I tried adding this to my CSS:

```
.border {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
margin-top: 2em;
}
```

and this to my haml

```
 .border  
  = render partial: 'stepwizard', locals: {active: 'payment'}
  = render partial: 'form-payment', locals: {quotation_request:@quotation_request}
```

and it's not working. Any ideas on how I can get it to work?

Comment: what does your generated markup looks like? View it in the browser inspector. Is the border div correctly wrapping the partials? Is the class/style applied?

Comment: yes, the div was correctly wrapping the partials, but the styling had not been applied because I wasn't putting the css in the right place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried adding this inside the .border class definition?

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your partials inside whatever class you assigned for that border.
Let's say your border-class is `.border` and defined like this:

```
.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Then you want to wrap your partials inside an HTML element with this class like so:

```
.border  
  = render partial: 'stepwizard', locals: {active: 'payment'}
.border
  = render partial: 'form-payment', locals: {quotation_request:@quotation_request}
```

This would render each of your partials inside a div with the class `border` which in return has a border around it defined in your CSS.

Your approach described in the first post looks basically like this. So I assume your problem is either that you did not indent the partials properly or the CSS gets overwritten. For that matter, please create a JSFiddle or provide more information.